# GWT - Two Question on Hyperlink - Manage its History token parameter + insert it in a span

Tags: gwt, hyperlink, gwt-history

I need to manage a Hyperlink object in GWT. What i need is :

**1 - add it into a span (like InlineLabel)**

I tried `Hyperlink affitta_3_span_1=new Hyperlink(result.get(i)[0], "");`, but it create somethings like this :

```
<div class="affitta_3_span_1">
    <a href="#">t1</a>
</div>
```

in fact i need this :

```
<span class="affitta_3_span_1">
    <a href="#">t1</a>
</span>
```

**2 - manage Hyperlink History token**

I put my internal links such `Hyperlink affitta_3_span_1=new Hyperlink(result.get(i)[1], "article/"+result.get(i)[0])` but i don't know how to get the parameter on token when they call the onValueChange() function. How can I do it?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `Anchor`.  The output is just an `<a>` tag that has no `<div>` *or* `<span>` around it, but if you need a `<span>` you can add it with an HTML panel.

To set a URL that history can access, just put a `#` at the beginning.  Something like

```
myAnchor.setText(result.get(i)[1]);
myAnchor.setUrl("#article/"+result.get(i)[0]);
```

Now, when you click myAnchor, onValueChange will be passed the token "article/whatever".  The unfortunate side effect is that your urls look like http://example.com/#article/whatever, but that's the only way to get the token to the History object with just GWT.

Comment: Uhm...ok! This strategy seems to work with Hyperlink too! I don't understand how to pick the parameter on my token value when i use getToken from onValueChange. I need a sort of stringtokenizer?

Comment: Yes, you need a string tokenizer or some other mechanism that turns "article/whatever" into something meaningful to your application.

Comment: Ah ok. I hope GWT give some other further method (with parameter check/validation, and so on). Ok, i'll do my own function for this :) With your experience : you suggest to use Anchor or Hyperlink?

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, use an `Anchor` since it's inlined.

For the second one, you need to 'listen' to history change events by extending `ValueChangeHandler` and calling `History.addValueChangeHandler(this);` in your class. For example,

```
class MyClass implements ValueChangeHandler<String> {
  public MyClass {
     ...
     History.addValueChangeHandler(this);
  }   

  @Override
  public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
    String token = event.getValue();
    if (token.equals("foo")) {
      // go to one page
    } else if token.equals("bar")) {
      // go to another page
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a ClickHandler on your link and no history support, you can use the [Anchor](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Anchor.html) widget, which is based on an `<a>` tag that has `display: inline` by default.

Comment: Ehm, yes...i need History support :)